# Deploy angular application on nginx server with Docker Welcome to nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, deployment, production

I developed an **Angular 7** application and now I'm going to deploy it on production server on an nginx server. I'm pretty new to frontend deployment on **nginx** server, so probably I'm missing something easy to find. I decided to use **Docker** to manager the deployment.

The application name is `MyWalletFe`.

---

### nginx server configuration file

Path: `./conf/default.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

### Dockerfile

```
# build
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# deploy
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Where I copy my nginx configuration file in the default location, then I copy the output of `npm run build` from previous stage in the `/usr/share/nging/html`.

## Output

I always get the default nginx webpage:
[image]
And the reason why this happens is that the folder `/app/dist` contains a subfolder with the name of the app, `MyWalletFe`, which contains all the file of the Angular application (the image is taken after run locally `npm run build` to show the folder structure):

[image: Folder structure]

while on the production server in folder `/usr/share/nginx/html` there is still the default `index.html` with this page that is served.

```
root@3b7da83d2bca:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  494 Mar  3 14:32 50x.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 20:32 MyWalletFE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612 Mar  3 14:32 index.html
```

I think that for this to work the content of `MyWalletFe` folder should be copied to the parent folder (`/usr/share/nginx/html`); in this case `default.conf` or `Dockerfile` contain some errors.
Is there something that is configured in a wrong way? In Resources section I've added the article which I followed.

### Resources

[Angular in Docker with Nginx](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can add the command to remove the default nginx index page just before copying

```
COPY ./conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*  <--- add this
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and change your nginx config to :

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
```

Comment: Thank you! So the problem was the default files in `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.. Why do I have to modify the nginx config in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line of your docker file to:

```
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /var/www/html/
```

And for single-page applications like Angular, you should change your Nginx config to this:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the cause can be the most stupid thing, having something like this in my angular.json:

```
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
```

that was causing my app was copied to **/usr/share/nginx/html/my-app**

I hope you don't waste several hours breaking your mind like me :||

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Angular 17, there's been a small change in the position of the main folder: instead of being directly in the dist or even the folder specified for you, there's a new subfolder called browser. browser has become the main folder in which your index.html can be found after the build.
A small change will therefore take place in the docker file :

## You must add browser to path

```
# build
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# deploy
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# You must add browser to path

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
```